# get class of selected item Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a select list with a changing ID, whose selected item's value I am able to reference from the id of the div it resides in thusly:

```
var weight = parseFloat(\$(\".divInner select\").val());
```

I'm having trouble determining how to get the selected item's class.
 How can I grab that class?

HTML

```
<div class="divInner">
    <select id="*(changes)*" class="option required" >
        <option class="0" value="">-- Select --</option>
        <option class="258" value="1.3200">Nifty Thing</option>
        <option class="232" value="0.5900">Snazzy Thing</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: the `{}` above the textarea element here is for making block code. Use it for better formatting. And do not put irrelevant tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) option in JQuery:

```
$('div.divInner select option:selected').attr('class');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This actually was the first thing I tried, and at that point nothing was working for me, leading me to try other options.  My real problem was, I was trying to set a variable I'd named class with this value.  Changing my variable name to sel_class allowed all to work properly.